# Iterate over one key's dictionary in another dictionary in a Django template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I have a dictionary that looks like the following:

```
timeTables = {
        'today': {'date_start': datetime.now(), 'date_end': None},
        'yesterday': {'date_start': (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)), 'date_end': None},
        'week': {'date_start': (datetime.now() - timedelta(weeks=1)), 'date_end': datetime.now()},
        'month': {'date_start': (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)), 'date_end': datetime.now()},
    }
```

I want to output the `today` keys dictionary elements in a for loop within the Django template.

I can accomplish this in normal Python via:

```
for key, value in timeTables['today'].items():
        print key, value
```

But this same thing won't work in a Django template.

Doing this gives an error:

```
{% for key, value in data['today'].items %}
    {{ key }} {{ value }}
{% endfor %}

TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '['today'].items' from 'data['today'].items'
```

Comment: Did you try `data.today.items`?

Comment: @Fogest: despite being inspired by Python syntax, Django's template language is NOT Python. And FWIW Django's template language is documented here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/

Comment: @Holt you could put that as an answer if you'd like :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django templates, you cannot use the `data['today']` syntax to access the value of a dictionnary, you need to use the `.` (`data.today`):

```
{% for key, value in data.today.items %}
    {{ key }} {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
If you want only dictionary field with only 'today' key then simply send data['today'] from view {'data': data['today']} and then render it like:

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {{ key }} {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want whole dictionary to be sent then,

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {% for k,v in value.items %}
     {{k}} {{v}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The first solution involves me having to send a totally different dictionary which is not what I am asking, and the second solution just seems to go through the whole dictionary and not just the one key.